# Regular expression for replacing a first markdown/tag symbol

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
Hello, I'm your \||spoiler\|| and another one \||spoiler2\||
```

and I need to get

```
Hello, I'm your SPOILER: spoiler and another one SPOILER: spoiler2
```

out of it. I can't simply use `s.replaceAll("\\||", "SPOILER: ");` since it would replace the ending wrapping `\||` too. I was wondering if there's a regular expression that could help me out?

Comment: Please show us what the real input string is.  I doubt that the delimeter is `\||` with a single backslash.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is a single backslash. At least that is how it prints to a console. I use another library to escape markdown symbols. So I pass a `||spoiler||` to that library's `sanitize(String text)` method and it returns `\||spoiler\||`

Comment: I fixed my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the regex pattern `\\\|\|(.*?)\\\|\|` with the first capture group prefaced by `SPOILER :`:

```
String s = "Hello, I'm your \\||spoiler\\|| and another one \\||spoiler2\\||";
System.out.println(s);
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\\\|\\|(.*?)\\\\\\|\\|", "SPOILER: $1");
System.out.println(s);
```

This prints:

```
Hello, I'm your \||spoiler\|| and another one \||spoiler2\||
Hello, I'm your SPOILER: spoiler and another one SPOILER: spoiler2
```

Note that a literal backslash in a Java string literal takes *two* backslashes, and it takes four backslashes inside a regular expression string.  Also, `|` is a regex metacharacter, and so needs to also be escaped with two backslashes.

Comment: hm, if I replace `$1` with something else, say, 'dog' it would print `Hello, I'm your dog and another one dog`, this replacing the contents of the spoiler tags. While I need the contents to stay fixed, the later spoiler tag `||` be erased and the former `||` be replaced with `SPOILER: `.

Comment: @CyberWolf I think Tim just missed the new "SPOILER: " part. Simply use `SPOILER: $1` instead of `$1` for the replacement. See it here: https://regex101.com/r/CgBOLb/1

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Your solution works flawlessly and does exactly what I need. You saved me hours of frustration! Regex really look like magic, I want to learn it now.